# I forget/I am forgetting

Tags: semantics

I am forgetting German. (I am gradually forgetting my knowledge of German)

I forget German. (What does it mean? Does it mean that I don't remember it?)

Comment: Where did you read "I forget German"?  It doesn't seem to be a likely tense to use with the word "forget" in this context.

Comment: If "I am forgetting German" is OK why is "I forget (my) German" wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, it is just semantically unlikely.

For example when we are having food we normally talk about "chips"  using a plural word.  What is wrong with "fish and a chip"?  Nothing, except that it is unlikely to want to buy a single chip. So "Fish and a chip" is semantically unlikely.

There's nothing wrong, grammatically, with "I forget German", but it means "forget habitually or regularly", and learning a language is a big effort that you can't "learn then forget everyday".

That is just a strange combination of words.  It is fine to say "I forget my keys everyday" because that makes a common meaning.

Instead you would use a progressive form, to mean "in the process of forgetting, which will take some time" or a perfect form, to mean "I don't remember any more", or a past tense form, to mean "the process of forgetting was completed by this point in the past".

Comment: I see what you mean. My point was that "I forget my German" can mean "I don't remember my German", Or it can't, can it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in relation to a language learned but which is being lost over time, without practise, I'd put in 'my' and a qualifier afterwards.

> I forget my German - it's been so long since I got any real practice.

Comment: Not completely clear. Is your sentence supposed to mean that I don't remember it, not that I suffer a memory loss from time to time forgetting my German?

Comment: There's no indication as to whether this is a permanent or temporary situation. That would need further clarification, the same as any other similar statement. 'I am forgetting' would perhaps imply an ongoing situation. It would still be better with 'my'.

Comment: But "I don't remember my English" is unequivocally a permanent state without further clarification. How come "I forget my English" can be interpreted in two ways? I understand that you mean it can mean 1 I don't remember my English (always) 2 I forget my English (once in a while).

Comment: "unequivocally a permanent state" - no, it isn't. The rest of the argument falls at that first step.

Comment: Can you substantiate your contention? "1 I live in Tokyo. 2 I speak German 3 I remember your name. are sentences which convey a permanent state of actions. Do you agree? If you don't, why? By the same token "I don't remember my German" conveys a permanent action. Of course, if we added "sometimes, once in a while" it would change the meaning. But we don't have them in the original sentence. So, why is it not permanent?

Comment: The rest of the argument is focused on a different point, as a matter of fact.

Comment: If you want a specific answer, ask a specific question. Your OP is so vague it's anyone's guess what you actually need. Both your sentences would be improved by adding 'my' as an indicator that it'a a language that is being forgotten. As neither of your sentences makes much sense without further context, no-one can really tell you for certain "what they mean" which is all that your question asks.

Comment: What is not clear in this question " Does it mean that I don't remember it?"

Comment: Everything is 'not clear' in the question… but I'm done now. I'm not going to just argue with you because you can't post a clear question, add additional clarification when challenged, or even admit it's not a clear question. Enjoy your day.

Comment: Well, if this is not clear then what is clear? I forget German. (What does it mean? Does it mean that I don't remember it?)

Comment: You're just repeating yourself now. That is not adding clarity, just irritation.  If you want better answers ask better questions. There's an edit button right below your original post to do just that. I'm done now.

Comment: Yeah, but your complain is very vague, it's not clear what you don't understand in my question. Why edit it? All the best.